# handle a time object from php in flex (parse it to a Date object)

Tags: php, apache-flex, actionscript-3, date, time

I've got a php backend which delivers a time (e.g. '07:00:00').
This time is recognized as a string but I need it as a Date.

So what I need is:
Convert a string '07:00:00' to a Flex Date object.

Is there a way to do this (without using regular expressions)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- String.split(":") -> array of "07",
  "00", "00"
- parseInt on each part
- create date object and use setHours, 
  setMinutes and setSeconds methods.

Don't forget that newly created Date object presents current date.

Comment: This is like using regular expressions for me. I'm searching for something like the Date.parse() function.
But your answer is right, I should've been more detailled.

Comment: NB: in flex the days (Date.date) start at 1, but the months (Date.month) start at 0. Could miss this when converting from the PHP date. Little brat of a problem caught me out before!

Answer (score 0):

Use the Date class
http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/

Particularly the parse() property , but you should also be able to use a PHP timestamp and get the Date class to return a String

```
  //value returned from PHP
  var timestamp:Number = 1234670090;
  var date:Date = new Date(timestamp);

  var date2:Date = new Date();
  var time:String = date2.parse('07:00:00');

  // trace( date ) or trace( time ) should give you a String 
  //with the format Sat Nov 30 15:20:00 GMT-0800 1974
```

You can use the date variable's properties to return the year , month , day , hours, minutes etc...

Comment: Seems, that you missunderstood me:
I don't have a timestamp. All i got is '07:00:00'. And `Date.parse("07:00:00");` won't work.

Comment: Well. I assumed that if you could get a String from PHP, you should be able to get a timestamp, but if you can't , it wouldn't take much effort to transform your String into a format that could be parsed by the Date class. My guess is that the Date class expects a year, day & month where you're only providing the hours minutes & seconds, I haven't tested it but I'm pretty sure that by concatenating the missing info you would get what you're looking for.

Comment: The thing is: I don't care about year, month and day. It's just the time I need. Your guess about the Date class is right. I thought there is a possibility to leave the year, month and day empty.